# Native onKeyDown not firing in Modal for React Native Android

Tags: react-native

If, in my React Native application, I have some Java code like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KEYCODE_BUTTON_16) {
            rfidScanning.startScanning();
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
```

The contents of onKeyDown will be called unless I have a React Native Modal component visible.

Why does the modal visibility change this, and how can I make it fire anyway or do something equivalent (such as capturing the event somewhere else in my Java code)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think I found the problem.  It looks to me like the relevant modal code is here:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/b531612b2c917e1f2bd6bb37bf854fe51e658b36/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/modal/ReactModalHostView.java#L221

They actually handle the onKeyUp and not the onKeyDown.  I confirmed this by verifying in my own code that onKeyUp fires with the modal open, but onKeyDown does not.
Wow.
I created an issue document for the bug here:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32827